# Google Calendar API V3 doesn't respect timeMin timeMax parameters in nodejs Express application

Tags: node.js, express, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I've managed to get all events between two dates as mentioned in [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs) example on pure nodeJs environment.

But when i use same cording with nodeJs Express App, It doesn't respect the timeMin and timeMax parameters.

Instead, i get all the events from the date that i created first event on calendar. 
Here is my code block looks like.

```
function listEvents(auth) {
  var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
  calendar.events.list({
    auth: auth,
    calendarId: 'primary',

    timeMin: (new Date(Date.parse("2018-01-22"))).toISOString(),
    timeMax: (new Date(Date.parse("2018-02-27"))).toISOString(),

    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime'
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var events = response.items;
    if (events.length === 0) {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    }
    else {
       // Do Some Stuff ...............
    }
  });
}
```

What am i missing here..?

Comment: how long you been using Express? Try changing your date parameter to just "new Date()).toISOString()" as used in NodeJS quickstart. If it works, you have a problem with your date format.

Comment: New to express. i already tried that too. don't u think that it's their library issue bcz it is still marked as alpha version.

Comment: nodejs quickstart is working fine

Comment: yes it's working fine. try run same script with timeMin and timeMax inside express app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The starter example seems to be incorrect, but in line with the documentation.

V0.x of the google-auth-library uses the request library, so passing a querystring options does the trick:

```
calendar.events.list(
    {
        auth: auth,
        calendarId: 'primary',
    }, 
    { 
        qs: {
            timeMin: (new Date(Date.parse("2018-01-22"))).toISOString(),
            timeMax: (new Date(Date.parse("2018-02-27"))).toISOString(),
            singleEvents: true,
            orderBy: 'startTime'
        } 
    }, function(err, response) {
     ...
```

Answer url is [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/977#issuecomment-362333534)

Comment: this did not help, i am still getting results outside my bounds.... this is what my events list api call looks like ```const start = startDate.toISOString();
        const end = endDate.toISOString();
        return this.client.events.list({
            calendarId: process.env.GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID,
            timeMin: start,
            timeMax: end
        })```

Answer (score 1):

The quick start uses the older version of the google auth library. This made it work for me:

Update the libraries to the latest

```
npm i google-auth-library@latest
```

And in the quickstart file, update your code like this

```
let auth = google.auth;
```

and

```
let events = response.data.items;
```

Thanks to & modified from: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/946#issuecomment-360400714